# Setting up IPv6 internal network with WiFi access point

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ipv6

first of all I'm completely new to ipv6 so please forgive me if I'll say something stupid.
I'm trying to setup an ipv6 internal network to test an application I wrote ( yeah I can code for ipv6 but I can't setup it -.- ).

What I need is to configure a Linux laptop ( Ubuntu 14.04 ) as an "ipv6 only wireless access point" ( is it even possible? ) and then make my mobile device ( Android ) connect to it, everything on ipv6 ( basically I have to test nmap -6 ... from my android device ).

I can't seem to find any guide/tutorial to do this, any suggestions?

PS: I do not need to go "outside" this network ( no internet connectivity needed ).

Answer (score -1):

Macchina1
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 channel 4
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid 'evilsocket'
iwconfig wlan0 key 000000000f
ifconfig wlan0 inet6 add 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64
 
ifconfig wlan0 up
Macchina2
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 channel 4
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid 'evilsocket'
iwconfig wlan0 key 000000000f
ifconfig wlan0 inet6 add 2001:0db8:0:f101::2/64
 
ifconfig wlan0 up

Comment: Please add a little more explanation and formatting to your answer

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I need to do this with an Android phone as the client, it doesn't support ad-hoc natively :)